# Weird glitch with accordion-style script

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

No idea when or why this suddenly started happening which doesn't really help. >_<

This is my website: http://kaye.at/baby/

When 'August' is clicked and closed, it disappears and everything goes a bit glitchy! Doesn't seem to be happening on mobile safari though.

It doesn't seem to be a conflict as it still happens when I remove everything else 'Navigation/Header/Banner' off of the page.

Problem seems to occur no matter what month is at the top. If I remove 'August' it will happen to 'July'. :/

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. It was this on the CSS:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```